# How can I make this pagination menu work in Vue?

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel, vue.js

I installed laravel-vue-pagination by:

```sh
npm install laravel-vue-pagination
```

Then I registered it  globally in app.js:

```js
Vue.component('pagination', require('laravel-vue-pagination'));
```

Finally, I had menu's and each menu has categories while each category has products. Pagination is supposed to show 3 products per page. It showed first page and below it had the number of pages available, but the pages un-clickable. I clicked on page 2 or 3 and nothing happens.

```html
<div class="card-body">
    <body>
    <tbody>
        <template v-for="product in catProducts.data" v-if="product.CATUID === category.CATID">
            <tr>
                <td @click="editText(product.ID+'-descript')">
                    <span v-if="!show(product.ID+'-descript')">{{product.DESCRIPT}}</span>
                    <input v-if="show(product.ID+'-descript')" type="text" v-focus="focused" @focus="focused = true" v-model="product.DESCRIPT" @blur="hide(product.RID ,product.ID ,product.DESCRIPT, 'DESCRIPT')" @keyup.prevent.enter="hide(product.RID ,product.ID ,product.DESCRIPT, 'DESCRIPT')"></td>
                <td @click="editText(product.ID+'-tag1')">
                    <span v-if="!show(product.ID+'-tag1')">{{product.TAG1}}</span>
                    <input v-if="show(product.ID+'-tag1')" type="text" v-focus="focused" @focus="focused = true" v-model="product.TAG1" @blur="hide(product.RID ,product.ID ,product.TAG1, 'TAG1')" @keyup.prevent.enter="hide(product.RID ,product.ID ,product.TAG1, 'TAG1')"></td>
                <td @click="editText(product.ID+'-tag2')">
                <span v-if="!show(product.ID+'-tag2')">{{product.TAG2}}</span>
                <input v-if="show(product.ID+'-tag2')" type="text" v-focus="focused" @focus="focused = true" v-model="product.TAG2" @blur="hide(product.RID ,product.ID ,product.TAG2, 'TAG2')" @keyup.prevent.enter="hide(product.RID ,product.ID ,product.TAG2, 'TAG2')"></td>
                <td @click="editText(product.ID+'-price')">
                <span v-if="!show(product.ID+'-price')">{{product.PRICE}}</span>
                <input v-if="show(product.ID+'-price')" type="text" v-focus="focused" @focus="focused = true" v-model="product.PRICE" @blur="hide(product.RID ,product.ID ,product.PRICE, 'PRICE')" @keyup.prevent.enter="hide(product.RID ,product.ID ,product.PRICE, 'PRICE')"></td>
            </tr>
        </template>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

And:

```html
<pagination :data="catProducts" @pagination-change-page="getResults(category.CATID)"></pagination>
```

The only difference between github and mine is adding CATID to the ajax:

```js
getResults(catid, page = 1) {
                axios.get('api/getproducts/'+this.restid+'/'+catid+'?page=' + page)
                    .then(response => {
                        this.products = response.data;
                    });
            },
```

Any idea how to make pagination menu work?

Comment: `div -> body -> tbody` does not look like any kind of correct HTML hierarchy

Answer (score 0):

Odd HTML hierarchy aside, you're not capturing the selected page from the `pagination-change-page` event

Try using the following (note the use of `$event`)

```html
<pagination
  :data="catProducts"
  @pagination-change-page="getResults(category.CATID, $event)"
></pagination>
```

You can also clean up your `getResults` method a little

```js
async getResults (catid, page = 1) {
  const url = `api/getproducts/${encodeURIComponent(this.restid}/${encodeURIComponent(catid)}`
  const { data } = await axios.get(url, { params: { page } })
  this.products = data;
},
```